# How to append appium server logs

Tags: appium

**Use Case :**

I have around 10 Test cases , each test cases on run create appium session one by one , However each time the logs are getting overwrite, is there any option in appium CLI where i can append the logs so that i have log of all the 10 test cases in one single file.

**What i tried**

```
appium -p 4723 --log appium.log
```

**What i am trying to avoid**

```
appium -p 4723 --log appium.log>>complete.log
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no Appium-side CLI argument to do this, but you can just redirect standard error to standard output to make sure you catch all log messages and use built-in shell to append the output to the file:

```
appium -p 4723 2>&1 >> complete.log
```

Should you want to see the logs as you're doing the tests, you can use `tee`:

```
appium -p 4723 2&>1 | tee -a complete.log
```